# How can I find what my IP is from a pcap file?

Tags: ip, wireshark, network-analysis

I try to analyze some pcap files that I got in my hands, but I need to sort out the packets that have my IP in them. I don't know what "my" IP is, because the capture didn't take place on my pc. How can I tell which IP is mine?

Comment: What kind of traffic is in the file?  HTTP? SSH? Something else?

Comment: HTTP (I needed some more characters :) )

Answer (score 0):

If your IP address hasn't changed since the trace was gathered, just get your IP address using *ifconfig* (Linux or MacOS) or the networking control panel in Windows.

If your PC's address has changed since the packets were captured,
use Wireshark to filter out the non-HTTP packets.  Then look for packets that have *GET* or *POST* as part of the packet.  Those packets are from the client (usually someone's pc or phone) to a server.  Look for a request to a server that you access and no one else does (like StackOverflow).  The source IP is the address of your PC.

Comment: It is a good approach, but the pcap is not taken from my pc, or even from me.

Answer (score 0):

See the some session. 
You can find this Common point.

## example

192.168.1.10 <-> **192.168.1.9**

**192.168.1.9** <-> 8.8.8.8

192.168.1.100 <-> **192.168.1.9**

192.168.1.123 <-> **192.168.1.9**

192.168.1.199 <-> **192.168.1.9**

**192.168.1.9** <-> 192.168.1.90

...

So, Your IP is 192.168.1.9!